# Import Order/Invoice/Credit Memos/ Transaction/ Comment History

Tags: magento2

Is there anyways we can import the Order/Invoice/Credit Memos/ Transaction/ Comment History to M2 from M2.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, to add extra data to the existing tables, write script to copy the records from one table to another.

Method 1:

1. Connect with the database
2. Get the data from CSV file (Export/Download the data in CSV format)
3. Insert the data into new table

Method 2:

Place table1(data that you are going to transfer) and table2(destination table) to same database

1. Connect with the database
2. Write script to copy the records from table1 to table2